# Sequelize saving many to many

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I was wandering if there are any extended tutorials on how to save a many to many relationship? I find the documentation more than basic. Its missing many use case examples.

I have two models: Client and Rule. They have the n:n relationship.

Client:

```
var Client = sequelize.define('client', {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
      allowNull: false
    },
    company: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
        allowNull: false
    },
    vendor: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false
    },
    consumer: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: true
    },
    address_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    }
  },{
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true,
    classMethods: {
      associate:function(models){
          Client.hasMany(models.rule, { through: 'client_rules', onDelete: 'cascade'});
      }
    }
  });
```

Rule:

```
var Rule = sequelize.define('rule', {

    service_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    is_allowed: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false
    },
    valid_until: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    rule: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER, // 1 for company rule, 2 for individual rule
      allowNull: false, 
    },
    active: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: true
    }

  },{
    underscored: true,
    paranoid: true,
    classMethods: {
      associate:function(models){
          Rule.belongsToMany(models.client, { through: 'client_rules', onDelete: 'cascade'});
          Rule.belongsTo(models.service, { foreignKey: 'service_id' } );

      }
    }
  });
```

Now I would like to create a new rule for client. So I would have to create the rule first and associate it then to the client through 'client_rules'.

How do I do that with sequelize? This doesn't work:

```
var clientID = req.user.client_id;
Client.find({ id: clientID })
.then(function(client){
  return client.addRule(req.body)
})
.catch(function(err){
  console.log(err)
})

[TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found out how to do it. The docs are very confusing.

```
    var clientID = req.user.client_id;
    return Rule.create(req.body)
    .then(function(newRule){
          var ruleToAdd = newRule;
          return Client.findOne({ where: { id: clientID } })
    .then(function(client){
            return client.addRule(ruleToAdd)
            .then(function(ans){
              return ruleToAdd;
            })
    })
```

Comment: can you do it in one statement?

Comment: I tried to use your example, but where have you define addRule? can you give a code example of this method?

Comment: Since the model is called "Rule" and the relationship is many to many, you can just call add{yourModel}